# limit file size for jpg and pdf uploads

Tags: php, upload-max-filesize

I'm not skilled in php, but I have found a snippet that will limit my users from uploading 'image' files to my wordpress site, that are larger than 1mb. (I'll edit this limit to suit my requirements).
I'm assuming 'image' files are jpg, png, etc. 
**But what about pdf files, will this snippet limit them too, or are they not classified as 'image' type files?**

Ideally, I need to limit jpg and pdf files. Does this need modification?

```
// WP - LIMIT IMAGE UPLOAD SIZE
function max_image_size( $file ) {
$size = $file['size'];
$size = $size / 1024;
$type = $file['type'];
$is_image = strpos( $type, 'image' ) !== false;
$limit = 1024;  
$limit_output = '1MB';
if ( $is_image && $size > $limit ) {
$file['error'] = 'Image files must be smaller than ' . $limit_output;
}//end if
return $file;
}//end max_image_size()
add_filter( 'wp_handle_upload_prefilter', 'max_image_size' );
```

( Using php 7.2 )
Thanks in advance,
Chris.

Comment: Nope - this is only a part (a filter) of the necessary checks. It analyses a $file and returns a possible error-message as part of the $file-array. You will need the part where files are uploaded, too. The standard-way is to upload the files and afterwards it will be checked, if you want to keep the data or not. And finally - no, PDFs are not included.

Comment: Thanks, I have added this to my child theme (functions.php) and it works ok for image file limits. I should have mentioned this, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to limit all the resources replace:

```
if ( $is_image && $size > $limit ) {
  $file['error'] = 'Image files must be smaller than ' . $limit_output;
}//end if
```

with:

```
if ( $size > $limit ) {
  $file['error'] = 'Files must be smaller than ' . $limit_output;
}//end if
```

Optional [1]: you can rename the max_image_size function to max_file_size and change the addfilter to add_filter( 'wp_handle_upload_prefilter', 'max_file_size' );

Optional [2]: you can detect the PDF mime type, which is application/pdf by using:

```
$is_pdf = strpos( $type, 'pdf' ) !== false;
```

and add other condition:

```
if ( $is_image && $size > $limit ) {
  $file['error'] = 'Image files must be smaller than ' . $limit_output;
}//end if
if ( $is_pdf && $size > $limit ) {
  $file['error'] = 'PDF files must be smaller than ' . $limit_output;
}//end if
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try the above solutions. Does the first solution mean that I can omit the following two lines from the original snippet, as these identify the file type, which is no longer required?

      $type = $file['type'];
      $is_image = strpos( $type, 'image' ) !== false;

Also, just to check, will this only place a limit on front-end uploads, and not stop me from adding larger files as an admin? or plugins etc...